# "Missing Privacy Policy"Email from Facebook

Tags: facebook

Even though I have linked both Terms & Privacy policys in my facebook App.  I have recieved 2 warning through my email to add the policy links.  I have double checked and the links work perfectly.

Anyone else recieve these emails, whilst, having the links added.

Thanks

Comment: This is something you need to query with Facebook, I don't see how it fits in here.

Comment: If alot of people have the same issue, wouldnt it be classified as a bug report.  Thats why it fits in here.

Comment: Since when are Facebook bug reports on topic? Take a look at the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and check out _What kind of questions can I ask here?_

Comment: I agree, this is not the place to post bug reports. Contact Facebook for that. There's nothing we can do for you. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

I just received our second notification, also stating we don't have a valid policy URL, when in fact it's perfectly valid, can be seen on the Auth page, and returns the correct content. I've filed a bug with Facebook, as I believe this is caused by their internal redirector not working, and thus valid URLs are tested as invalid. You can subscribe/add to it here:

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/345349798879609

Comment: There is another bug report regarding this here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/121327261346922